# Quartz xml configuration

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler, quartz-core

I want to run Quartzjob through xml configuration along with Tomcat Server.But when I start Tomcat my job is not at all starting.
could any one help ?
Here is My code:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
       org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

MyJob.java

```
package com.cron;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;


public class MyJob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
     throws JobExecutionException {

      System.out.println("Cron executing ");

    }
}
```

quartz-config.xml under project src folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job-scheduling-data
    xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"

    version="1.8">

    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>FirstJob</name>
            <group>DummyGroup</group>
            <description>This is FirstJob</description>
            <job-class>com.cron.MyJob</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>dummyTrigger</name>
                <job-name>FirstJob</job-name>
                <job-group>GroupDummy</job-group>
                <!-- It will run every 2 seconds -->
                <cron-expression>0/2 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

quartz.properties file under project src folder

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class =org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames =quartz-config.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
```

when i start Tomcat server the log it is showing below

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Apr 12, 2015 4:39:28 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8441
Apr 12, 2015 4:39:28 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8442
Apr 12, 2015 4:39:28 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/46  config=null
Apr 12, 2015 4:39:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1208 ms
```

The list of JAR files i have used below:

```
quartz-2.2.1.jar
quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
jta-1.1.jar
```

Comment: What are you using to build and deploy your application?

Comment: I am using eclipse to build and deploy the application

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener and I am using servlet approach instead.

```
<!--Quartz-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
    <init-param> 
        <param-name>config-file</param-name> 
        <param-value>META-INF/quartz.properties</param-value> 
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```